# Check if file exist in C. If so continue read the last value of the file and increment by one

Tags: c, printf, scanf, fopen, file-exists

Even if I delete the " *file.txt* " the program still enters the `if` statement.

What I want to achieve is to check if there is a file with that name. If so then read the last value of `BookId` and increment it by one with `for` loop:

```
FILE *myFile;  

if (myFile==NULL) // if the file doesn't exists
{

    myFile=fopen("file.txt","w"); // Fresh write

    fprintf(myFile, "%s\t%s\t%s\t\n\n",Book_Id,Record_Date,Book_Name); // Column name (id, date, name)

    //writing the values
    for (x=0;x<NR_OF_BOOKS; x++)
    {
        fprintf(myFile, "%03d\t",BookId++);
        fprintf(myFile, "%02d/%02d/%04d\t",dd[x],mm[x],yy[x]);
        fprintf(myFile, "%s\n",Bookname[x]);
    }
}

else // file exists
{

    //reading
    myFile=fopen("file.txt","r"); //open in read mode
    fscanf(myFile,"%03d,",&BookId);  // I want to read the last value of BookId
    myFile=fopen("file.txt","a"); // I open in append  mode to add BookId++

    for (x=0;x<NR_OF_BOOKS; x++)
    {
        fprintf(myFile, "%03d\t",BookId++); // here continues to count the BookId
        fprintf(myFile, "%02d/%02d/%04d\t",dd[x],mm[x],yy[x]); // date
        fprintf(myFile, "%s\n",Bookname[x]);// book name
    }
}

fclose(myFile); // closing the file
}
```

Comment: Your first if statement makes no sense because your variable isn’t defaulted to null when you decalre it.  If you set the first line as myFile = null then your code would work. The way you have it means it is initialised with undefined value.

Answer (score 3):

Begin by trying to open the file for reading. If that doesn't work (`fopen` returns `NULL`) then you try to open for writing. And if that doesn't work either, you bail.

With your code:

```
FILE *myFile = fopen("file.txt", "r+");

if (myFile != NULL)
{
    // File exists and is now open for reading and writing...
}
else
{
    myFile = fopen("file.txt", "w");
    if (myFile == NULL)
    {
        // Report error and handle it appropriately
    }

    // The file didn't exist, now it is created so we can write to it
}

// All done with the file
fclose(myFile);
```

---

I recommend you consider using functions for common code.

Comment: Thank you  I achieved it. But how can I read the last value of BookId stored in the file and then increment it by one with the for loop ?

Comment: You must parse your file to work out that information.